# php usleep with simultaneous requests

Tags: php

I've been playing around with the ApacheBench ([ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)) command line utility but I'm not sure if it's the right tool for what I'm trying to do.

I was running 10 concurrent and 10 requests doing an INSERT into a MySQL table and looking at `round(microtime(1) * 10000)` to see if I was getting the same values.

I would like to know if using delayed execution `usleep()` is enough to prevent two simultaneous requests getting the same value on the same box, or is `time_sleep_until` better.

I know I could set more entropy with `uniqid()`.

So I'm just wondering if using delayed execution will be enough to prevent two exact time stamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know if `round(microtime(1) * 10000)` can give duplicate values? Well of course it can, I don't think you need to test for this.

`uniqid` is also not guaranteed to be unique, even with more entropy.

If uniqueness is really important you could always use MySQL with a UNIQUE index to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: I always test, Stackoverflow mentions in the "how to Ask", sharing research helps everyone and it demonstrates weve taken the time to try to help ourselfs.

Comment: That's commendable. Typically when you need to do a very specific task, like generating a unique number there is some function for it. But thing like randomness and uniqueness are computationally *hard*.